# How to debug Node.js app inside goormIDE with Chrome DevTools?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

In my local machine, I can debug my Node.js app with Chrome DevTools.
Since using goormIDE I have no idea how to debug it in the same way.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. In goormIDE, run your Node.js app with option `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229`

   For example, `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 app.js`

   `0.0.0.0` is to allow the connection from DevTools, which is outside of the goormIDE container.

   And `9229` is to specify the port that will be using.
2. Open menu `CONTAINER` - `Port Forwarding Configuration` and register a port `9229`
3. Click the copy button at the `Command` column, then the IP:port value will be copied.
   [image]
4. In Chrome, open a new tab and go to `chrome://inspect`
5. Enable `Discover network targets` option and click `Configure...` at the right.
6. Paste the IP:port value you copied at step 3, and press Enter then click `Done`.
7. Then you may see your app is listed at `Remote Target` and ready to be inspected.